# Как вывести имена из базы MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Как вывести из базы в колонке `xfields` только слово после `|label|` не во всех ячейках они присутствуют.

Эти я чейки с таким содержанием
`audio|name.mp3||image|name.jpg||wave|name.jpg||data|06.03.2017||label|Vision`

или

`audio|name.mp3||image|name.jpg||wave|name.jpg||data|06.03.2017`

или

`audio|name.mp3||image|name.jpg||wave|name.jpg||label|Vision`

Должно получится примерно так:

Vision   -  50 треков

Spinnin  -  35 треков

Sony     -  20 треков

....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаем по порядку, этот код выводит все поля `xfields`

`audio|name.mp3||image|name.jpg||wave|name.jpg||data|06.03.2017||label|Vision`

и т.д. Как вывести из этой строки только слово `Vision`? И Подсчитать в скольких ячейках оно присутствует?

```
<?php
if(!defined('DATALIFEENGINE')) {
die("Hacking attempt!");
}
global $config;
$limit = $limit ? intval($limit) : "20";
if (!$r_short) {
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . PREFIX . "_post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,{$limit}");
while ($row = $db->get_row($sql)) { 
$r_short .= "<p>{$row['xfields']}</p>";
}
}
echo $r_short;
?>
```

PS

Сделал чтобы выводились только эти слова, которые после `label|`. Нужно теперь чтобы повторяющиеся слова подсчитывались, и не выводилась пустота, если нет в ячейке слова `label|`.

```
<?php
if(!defined('DATALIFEENGINE')) {
die("Hacking attempt!");
}
global $config;
$limit = $limit ? intval($limit) : "20";
if (!$r_short) {
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . PREFIX . "_post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,{$limit}");

while ($row = $db->get_row($sql)) {
echo '<p>';
echo explode('label|', $row['xfields'])[1];
echo '</p>';
}
}
echo $r_short;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас на корню не правильный подход к решению обычных задач. 
Вот один из вариантов решения задачи:

Вам нужно реализовать связи между таблицами. В вашей таблице, колонки `xfields` не должно быть в принципе. 
Вместо этой колонки, нужно завести отдельную таблицу в базе данных `xfields`.

Вы не привели название текущей вашей таблицы, поэтому дадим ей название `popka`
Структура таблицы `xfields` будет примерно такая:
`id` - айдишник
`xfield` - ваш кейворд
`popka_id` - айдишник, элемента (хозяина) в таблице `popka`

Таким образом, для того чтобы получить кол-во "xfield'ов" например для элемента `popka` с `id` 123  достаточно выполнить следующий запрос

```
SELECT count(*) from `xfields` where `xfields`.`popka_id` = 123
```

для того чтобы подсчитать сгруппированное кол-во "хфилдов" для "попки" 123 запрос не мудреный:

```
SELECT count(*) as 'count', `xfield` FROM `xfields` WHERE `xfields`.`popka_id`=123 GROUP BY `xfields`.`xfield` ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Ну и естественно, при создании нового xfield'a нужно указывать хозяина, которому данный xfield принадлежит.

Comment: Таблица же в коде написана `FROM " . PREFIX . "_post ` Отдельную таблицу завести не могу, это двиг сайта так пишет и многое связано с этой таблицей (поиск и т.п.).

Comment: Как это всё собрать?

Comment: Поменял строку вывода `$r_short .= "<p>...`  на эту `echo explode('label|', $row['xfields'])[1];` теперь выводятся только нужные слова. Как подсчитать повторение этих слов и как ещё `<p></p>` к этой строке подставить?

Comment: ну вы сами выбрали путь страданий и мучений )

Comment: Какой ещё путь есть не меняя таблицы?

Comment: ну гавнокодить дальше.
Как бы там нибыло, нужно организовать нормальную структуру базы данных. Хорошо продуманная структура позволяет просто и эффективно пользоваться данными. Поэтому я повторюсь, менять двиг ваш или обтачивать его по людски. Вооружится книгами и тд итп.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот вы перебираете результы своего запроса по строкам `while ($row = $db->get_row($sql)) { }`. Ну и всё. Перед этим циклом заводите счётчик или массив. Каждое получаемое в цикле значение режете по делителю `'|'` функцией `explode(delimiter, string)`. В результате получаете массив всех значений в вашей строчке. Ну а дальше уже делаете с этим массивом что душе угодно, Перебираете, сравниватете, получаете по индексу. Счётчик увеличиваете свой, если нашли нужное. И т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Как то так:

```
select substring_index(substr(xfields,instr(concat('||',xfields),'||label|')+6),'|',1) label,
       count(1) cnt
  from x_post
 where concat('||',xfields) like '%||label|%'
 group by label
```

Для работы с такими строками изучите [строковые функции MySQL](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/String_functions.html). Хотя лучше было бы доработать структуру БД. Даже если данные в эту таблицу пишет некий движок можно доделать БД не меняя его кода. Для этого вам надо завести отдельную таблицу с полями post_id, key, val в которой бы ключи и их значения лежали бы отдельными строками. Заполнять эту таблицу можно автоматически триггером на изменение таблицы post. Триггер будет брать xfields, разбивать его на части по `||` и вставлять в отдельную таблицу отдельными строками. При некотором желании можно это сделать даже одним запросом.

А ваш php строку получал не правильно. Так как это некий движок, то вы не можете гарантировать что поле label будет последним. И если оно будет не последним ваш explode даст неверный результат.

Comment: Я с выводом разобрался, там в движке оказывается уже настроена работа с массивами, мне нужно только это сгруппировать, но это уже в другом вопросе, только его указали как дубликат. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635804/

Comment: @steep А чем же он таким отличается от этого ? Вы в этом вопросе то же просили сгруппировать вы же тут написали "_Должно получится примерно так:

Vision - 50 треков

Spinnin - 35 треков

Sony - 20 треков_" и мой ответ именно так сгруппировано и выдает ...

Comment: Вы ещё скажите, что картинки одинаковые. Вы посмотрите мой код в другом вопросе, там реализация без `explode`, если бы я сделал как писали здесь в ответах, я бы другого вопроса не задал. А если решение другое, я задал новый вопрос.

Comment: @steep Хорошо, давайте так, чем отличается вывод приведенного мной запроса от того, что вы хотели получить для этого вопроса и чем он отличается от того вывода который вы ожидаете от ответа на тот второй вопрос

Comment: Вы же выше сами писали чем отличается ` И если оно будет не последним ваш explode даст неверный результат.` По этому и сделал настройками движка.

Comment: @steep Это ваш код в вопросе отличается, отлично. Но разве суть самого вопроса от этого изменилась ? Суть обоих вопросов "как получить все label и количество треков с ними" или я чего то не понимаю и суть вопросов разная ?