# Как сгруппировать данные из поля в базе Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот код выводит из поля `xfields` список всех ячеек.
Т.е из массива ключ `label`

```
Vision
Vision
Vision
Sony
Spinnin
Spinnin
...
```

А нужно примерно так.

```
Vision - 3 треков
Sony - 1 треков
Spinnin - 2 треков
...
```

В принципе подойдёт и без количества, главное чтобы в одном экземпляре, но с цифрой было бы лучше.

```
<?php
if (!defined('DATALIFEENGINE')) {
    die("Hacking attempt!");
}
global $config;
$limit = $limit ? intval($limit) : "20";
if (!$r_mlabel) {
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . PREFIX . "_post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,{$limit}");
    while ($row = $db->get_row($sql)) {
        $xfieldsdata = xfieldsdataload($row['xfields']);
        $r_mlabel.= "<a href=\"/xfsearch/" . $xfieldsdata['label'] . "/\">{$xfieldsdata['label']}</a>";
    }
}
echo $r_mlabel;
?>
```

Comment: вы ведь уже получили 2 ответа на этот вопрос тут - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635680/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-mysql

Comment: Почему дубликат? По тому вопросу помогли вывести, а по этому нужно сгруппировать.

Comment: Вы приводите несколько разновидностей одной и той же проблемы. Важно понять, что если проблема одна, то и вопрос должен быть один. Согласитесь, если у двух квадратных уравнений будут разные свободные члены, мы все равно будем использовать все те же формулы для нахождения корней.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полностью рабочий вариант

```
if (!$r_mlabel) {
$sql = $db->query("SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( p.xfields, 'label|', -1 ) ,  '||', 1 ) as xf_label, count(*) as count
                   FROM dle_post p
                   WHERE LOCATE('label|',p.xfields)>0
                   GROUP BY xf_label
                   ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 0,{$limit}
");
while ($row = $db->get_row($sql)) {
    $xfieldsdata = xfieldsdataload($row['xfields']);
    $r_mlabel.= "<a rel=\"ajaxlink\" class=\"mlabel\" href=\"/xfsearch/" . $row['xf_label'] . "/\">{$row['xf_label']}<span>{$row['count']}</span></a>";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Удалите этот вопрос и вернитесь к тому, который задали 6 часов назад [по этой ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/635680/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-mysql)

```
$all=[];

while ($row = $db->get_row($sql)) {
    $arr=explode('|',$row['xfields']);
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value)) continue;
        if (array_key_exists($value, $all)) $all[$value]=$all[$value]+1; else $all[$value]=1;
    }
}
print_r($all);
```

Comment: Вопросы разные, там вывести, а здесь сгруппировать и посчитать.

Comment: Так не делается. Вам следует дополнить и исправить ваш вопрос. Как сгруппировать и посчитать я вам в том вопросе уже ответил.

Comment: `Ну а дальше уже делаете с этим массивом что душе угодно, Перебираете, сравниваете, получаете по индексу. Счётчик увеличиваете свой, если нашли нужное. И т.д.` Это не ответ.

Comment: Массив я вывел и ключ нужный из него, теперь надо это сгруппировать как-то.

Comment: Теперь смотрим на код (в моём ответе выше) и на то, что я тебе писал в том вопросе твоём. Потом снова на код. Потом снова на то, что я тебе написал. И опять на код, и на то, что я написал. Всё ясно?

Comment: Опять `explode`, вы мой код смотрели? Я вывел из массива ключ другим способом, более точным, вот он `{$xfieldsdata['label']}`

Comment: слушайте, что вы хотите? Вы хотели получить сортировку и подсчёт - вы получили. Что вам ещё надо?

Comment: Издеваетесь? Какую сортировку? Мне нужно применить `GROUP BY` к выводу, я запутался с этими колонками

Comment: я конечно извиняюсь, но вы все запутали, а не только себя. Про sql в вашем вопросе ни слова. Вы написали, что хотите поучить метку и их количество из всего того, что вернул запрос. Я вам это сделал. Вы нормально объяснить в состоянии что вам надо?